# mysql create multiple select to put max in all rows

Tags: mysql

This is my table with sample data:

```
Table:PersTrans
+------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| PersTrID   | char(10)    | NO   | PRI |            |       |
| PersTrSeq  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0          |       |
| PersTrDate | date        | YES  |     | 1001-01-01 |       |
| PersTrPaid | float(9,2)  | YES  |     | 0.00       |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+

mysql> select * from PersTrans;
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| PersTrID   | PersTrSeq | PersTrDate | PersTrPaid |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| MOCK       |         1 | 2015-10-10 |     400.00 | 
| MOCK       |         2 | 2017-11-07 |      10.00 | 
| NAGA       |         1 | 2015-11-11 |     500.00 | 
| NASSA      |         1 | 2015-12-16 |     800.00 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I'd like to pick up the maximum PersTrSeq, and attach it to all the records that have the same PersTrId.   What I want:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
| PersTrID   | PersTrSeq | PersTrDate | PersTrPaid | max(PersTrSeq) |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| MOCK       |         1 | 2015-10-10 |     400.00 |              2 |
| MOCK       |         2 | 2017-11-07 |      10.00 |              2 |
| NAGA       |         1 | 2015-11-11 |     500.00 |              1 | 
| NASSA      |         1 | 2015-12-16 |     800.00 |              1 | 
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

These two attempts didn't work.  I've looked for other suggestions but haven't found anything helpful.

```
mysql> SELECT *, max(PersTrSeq) from PersTrans where PersTransId = 'Mock' group by PersTrSeq;
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+----------------+
| PersTrID   | PersTrSeq | PersTrDate | PersTrPaid | max(PersTrSeq) |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
| MOCk       |         1 | 2015-10-10 |     400.00 |              1 |
| MOCK       |         2 | 2017-11-07 |      10.00 |              2 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+

mysql> SELECT *, max(PersTrSeq) as maxseq from PersTrans group by PersTrId;
+------------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
| PersTrID   | PersTrSeq | PersTrDate | PersTrPaid | maxseq |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+
| MOCK       |         1 | 2015-10-10 |     400.00 |      2 |
| NAGA       |         1 | 2015-11-11 |     500.00 |      1 |
| NASSA      |         1 | 2015-12-16 |     800.00 |      1 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Can anyone offer a single query that will get the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will work:

```
select *,
       (select max(PersTrSeq) from PersTrans p2
        where p2.PersTrId = p1.PersTrId
       ) as maxSeq
from PersTrans p1;
```

Comment: This did indeed work.  I am unfamiliar with this syntax.  Could you direct me to some documentation of it, or maybe explain.  Thanks.

Comment: The query written after in parenthesis is an in-line subquery. It will be executed for each and every row of your table.

Comment: Hi Harshil, I knew about subqueries.  It is the part about the p1 and p2 I am unfamiliar with.  Seems like one is creating ghost tables on the fly here. ??

Comment: P1 & P2 are alias for the table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, you want the same number of records as the actual data, substituting the max(PersTrSeq) for all rows with a certain PersTrID.

```
SELECT 
    `PerTrID`,
    (SELECT max(`PersTrSeq`) FROM `PersTrans` b WHERE b.`PersTrID = a.`PersTrID`) as `PersTrSeq`,
    `PersTrDate`,
    `PersTrPaid`,
from `PersTrans` a
```

Comment: Yes, I got this to work.  I am a little confused by your use of the ` symbol.  I left it off.  I also had to add  "as maxseq" at the end of the 2nd select.

Comment: The backtic is used to quote column and table names. I use it out of habit to avoid parsing problem in case a table name or column name is a MySQL reserved word or function name, and to indicate a difference between values and column.